# If there is no cycle through $e$ and $g$, then all paths go through the same vertex

Tags: graph-theory

Suppose there is no cycle that goes through edges $e$ and $g$.  The question is to prove that for every path that begins at one of the vertices incident to $e$ and and ends at a vertex incident to $g$, that there exists some vertex $u$ that is always on that path.

**My work:**  Pick the edge closest to beginning vertex such that $e$ and this edge, call it edge $f_{j-1}$ (connection $v_{j-1}$ and $v_j$) do not form a cycle on the graph $G$.  Then using this cycle and a path joining a vertex on the cycle to one of the vertices $v_{j+1}, \ldots, v_n$, construct some contradiction by creating a cycle with edge $f_j$.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Anybody??  I have no idea

Comment: This is probably a different question than [Graph theory textbook proof...could someone explain what's going on?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1141534/graph-theory-textbook-proof-could-someone-explain-whats-going-on) but it seems like they would serve the same purpose to future readers, and the OP is satisfied either way.

Comment: @EricStucky How is it different?  Seems like the same question

Comment: @Goos: It's asking for clarification on a known proof as opposed to constructing a new one; in my (admittedly limited) experience mentoring students, that has been an important distinction.