# No cycle containing edges $e$ and $g$ implies there is a vertex $u$ so that every path sharing one end with $e$ and another with $g$ contains $u$

Tags: graph-theory, proof-explanation

There is a proof in my textbook for the following claim, which doesn't make a whole lot of sense to me.  My annotations are in **bold**.  Could someone perhaps elaborate on what's going on?

Claim.  If there does not exist a cycle containing edges $e$ and $g$ then there exists a vertex $u \in V (G)$ such that every path in $G$ sharing one end with e and another with $g$ contains $u$.

Proof: The claim trivially holds if $e$ or $g$ is a loop **OK**, so we assume that neither is. Let $P$ with vertex set $v_1, v_2, . . . , v_k,$ in order, be a path with $e$ joining $v_1$ to $v_2$ and $g$ joining $v_{k−1}$ and $v_k$. Let $f_i \in E(P_i)$ be the edge with ends $v_i$ and $v_{i+1}$. Let $j$ be chosen minimum so that no cycle in $G$ contains $e$ and $f_j$ **We can do this because we know that at least the edge $g$ will not create a cycle by assumption, right?**. We will show that $u = v_j$ satisfies the claim.

Suppose not. Let $C$ be a cycle containing $e$ and $f_{j−1}$ **What if $f_j = e$?  then what cycle? a single vertex?** and let $P′$ be a
path from an end of $e$ to an end of $f$ **Not sure what the book meant by $f$ here, any guesses?** avoiding $u$. Choose a subpath $Q$ of $P′$ with one end in $V (C)$ and another in ${v_{j+1}, v_{j+2}, . . . , v_k}$ as short as possible. Then $C \cup Q \cup P$ contains a cycle containing both $e$ and $f_j$, a contradiction. (The last statement requires some case checking.) **This ending seems a bit abrupt and non-obvious to me**

Thanks for the help

Comment: I meant if we pick $f_j = g$, then there is no cycle in $G$ with $e$ and $f_j$, therefore we are free to pick $j$ minimum where $f_j$ and $e$ do not have a cycle in $G$, yes?

Comment: Why do we know such a cycle exists?(in response to your second comment)

Comment: Let me do this in an answer, otherwise it is going to be a mess.

Comment: @Carol: If by annotation you mean the OP’s boldface, the $g$ in the first one is correct. If you’re talking about the third one, asking about the book’s $f$, then yes: it’s clearly supposed to be $g$.

Comment: Must we add an assumption that there must exist a cycle with $e$ in it?

Comment: Are you going to provide an answer?  Mostly the last part with the "case" checking

Comment: @ProbsNot: The case checking is a little messy, and I’m probably going to have to make some sketches in order to explain it clearly. I’ll post the rest of my answer now and add the last bit when I’m satisfied with the explanation.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to your first question is *yes*: we know that even if no smaller $j$ works, $j=k-1$ does.

Your next question identifies a genuine sloppiness in the argument. If $e$ is not part of any cycle, then $j=1$, and the argument has to be made differently. Suppose that $e$ is not part of any cycle. If there were a path from $v_1$ to either end of $g$ that did *not* use $e$, it together with $P$ would contain a cycle that included $e$, contrary to hypothesis. Thus, any path sharing one end with $e$ and the other with $g$ must contain $v_2$; i.e., we can take $u=v_2$.

With that special case out of the way we can assume that $j\ge 2$, and we’ve set $u=v_j$. We’re supposing that we have a cycle $C$ that contains $e$ and $f_{j-1}$ (which will also be $e$ if $j=2$). The book’s $f$ must be $g$: in order to get a contradiction we’re assuming that there is a path from one end of $e$ to one end of $g$ that avoids the vertex $u=v_j$. We know that $e$ is in the cycle $C$, so $P'$ has at least one vertex in $V(C)$. We also know that $P'$ includes an end of $g$ (once the typo is fixed), so it includes at least one of the vertices $v_{j+1},\ldots,v_k$, and we can choose $Q$ as described.

The ending is a bit abrupt, presumably because the author wants the reader to have the practice of filling in the necessary details. I’ll add an explanation, but I think that I’m going to have to make some sketches to accompany it, so it may be a little while.

**Added:** Here’s the basic sketch:

[image]

The horizontal black line represents $P$, the blue and red together are $P'$, the blue is $Q$, and the letter $C$ is sitting inside the cycle $C$. In this sketch if you start at $v_2$, the righthand end of $e$, follow $Q$ to the point at which it meets $P$, and head back along $P$ to $u$, you’ll use the edge $f_j$ to get to $u$. To complete the cycle so that it contains $e$, take the lower part of $C$ to $v_1$ and then close the cycle by taking $e$ to $v_2$.

This sketch goes with the case in which $P'$ goes from $v_2$ to an end of $g$. If $P'$ had gone from $v_1$ instead, you’d have had to use the top part of $C$ in the picture. In other words, in one case you want the part of $C$ that runs from $u$ to $v_1$ without using $e$ or $f_{j-1}$, and in the other case you want the part of $C$ that runs from $v_{j-1}$ to $v_2$ without using $e$ or $f_{j-1}$.

And of course it’s possible that the cycle $C$ minus the edges $e$ and $f_{j-1}$ actually has pieces that run from $u$ to $v_2$ and from $v_{j-1}$ to $v_1$ instead, hooking up the ends of $e$ and $v_{j-1}$ the other way around. That gives you another two cases, depending on the piece of $C-\{e,f_{j-1}\}$ to which $Q$ is attached. (In this sketch it’s the upper piece, running between $v_2$ and $v_{j-1}$.)

That’s certainly not a complete, detailed treatment of the cases, but it should at least give you a good start.

Comment: Ok thanks, I would appreciate those sketches.

Comment: Is it necessarily true that $C$ is disjoint from $P$ and $P'$ (obviously except for the critical intersections in the diagram above)?

Comment: @ProbsNot: No, that was just to keep the diagram reasonably clean. You will have to worry a little about that. For instance, if $C$ actually goes from $u$ to $v_{j+1}$ but is hooked up to $e$ as shown in the sketch, you won’t need $Q$ at all: the part of $P$ from $v_1$ to $v_{j+1}$ and the lower part of $C$ will do the trick. You also have to take a look at what happens when the lower part of $C$ shares at least one edge with $Q$; in that case you can go along that part of $C$ from $v_1$ to $Q$, then around the rest of $Q$ and back along $P$.